# Android Studio Calculation Result not response

Tags: java, android

I am inexperianced in Android Studio or Java and try to learn. I want to change values of 5 TextViews when Button click, based on some IF Conditions but nothing happens. I check the Logcat which informs

"Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."
My code is as below:

```
`btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Overridepublic void onClick(View v) {
            getCalculations();
        }
    });

}

private void getCalculations() {
            String valueT = txtT.getText().toString();
            String valueD = txtD.getText().toString();
            String valueS = txtS.getText().toString();
            String valueC = txtC.getText().toString();
            String valueA = txtA.getText().toString();
            int numberT = Integer.parseInt(valueT);
            int numberD = Integer.parseInt(valueD);
            int numberS = Integer.parseInt(valueS);
            int numberC = Integer.parseInt(valueC);
            int numberA = Integer.parseInt(valueA);
            if (numberT > 4 && numberD < 0){
                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(WalletActivity.this);
                adb.setTitle("Notice");
                adb.setMessage(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.massege2));
                adb.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        int scoreD = numberD -1;
                        int scoreT = numberT -5;
                        int scoreA = numberA -500;
                        txtT.setText(String.valueOf(scoreT));
                        txtD.setText(String.valueOf(scoreD));
                        txtA.setText(String.valueOf(scoreA));
                    }
                });
                adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
                adb.show();
            } else if (numberT > 4 && numberD == 0 && numberC < 10) {
                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(WalletActivity.this);
                adb.setTitle("Notice");
                adb.setMessage(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.massege2));
                adb.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        int scoreT = numberT -5;
                        int scoreA = numberA -500;
                        int scoreC = numberC +1;
                        int scoreS = numberS -1;
                        txtT.setText(String.valueOf(scoreT));
                        txtA.setText(String.valueOf(scoreA));
                        txtC.setText(String.valueOf(scoreC));
                        txtS.setText(String.valueOf(scoreS));
                    }
                });
                adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
                adb.show();
            }
            if (numberT > 4 && numberD == 0 && numberC == 10) {
                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(WalletActivity.this);
                adb.setTitle("Notice");
                adb.setMessage(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.massege3));
                adb.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
                adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
                adb.show();
            }
            if (numberT < 5) {
                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(WalletActivity.this);
                adb.setTitle("Notice");
                adb.setMessage(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.massege4));
                adb.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
                adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
                adb.show();
            }

        }
```

`

Comment: Nothing wrong i found till now from your code . Make sure your conditions are satisfying as no code is there out of the condition so by putting breakpoints or logs make sure conditions are satisfying

Comment: I didn't find anything wrong in the code you've presented, so it may be a problem outside of that scope. There's a lot that you could optimize in terms of readability though. Since most if statements include one another you could nest them e.g. check if `numberT > 4` and then check all others inside that. Furthermore a lot of that dialog code is doubled and could be moved to its own method that just takes in the onClick action.

Comment: I also think there is no error in code and the first condiotion is met as my numberT and numberD both are 5. However, Alert Dialog does not appear when I click the btn2.

Answer (score 0):

It is as logcat says. The main thread is being blocked due to code performing too many calculations on the UI thread.
Try doing all calculations on a separate thread and then joining to main (UI) thread on completion of your calculations.
The Android Activity is a linear UI thread - it will throw errors if it is getting even slightly blocked in its order of visible components update.

You will require some multithreading knowledge in at least Java to properly handle this.